# How can i do an AJAX post in ASP.NET MVC2?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

hello guys what is the best way to do an AJAX post using ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: you can give a look at this question [this]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787397/issue-while-store-the-javascript-textbox-value-into-db-using-ajax-code-in-mvc2/6787637#6787637)

Answer (score 3):

You need code on the client (browser) side to initiate the call, and the easiest way to do this is to use a Javascript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) which has integrated AJAX/JSON support. You'll find that jQuery is already in your Scripts folder if you have just used the Visual Studio template for an ASP.NET MVC project. Follow the link to the jQuery site and look at its `.ajax()` and `.json()` methods for more information.