# Issue while store the javascript textbox value into DB using ajax code in MVC2

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I may be missing something obvious here, but how could I rewrite this code!

i am trying here to store the value entered in the textbox(Textbox was showed in javascript dialog page).In a javascript dialog page i have one 'ok' button.. when i click the button i want to store the value entered in the textbox.I want to save the content using Ajax.

Please see my sample code
View page:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.button').live('click', function () {
            $('.Text_dialog').dialog('open');
        });

        $('.Text_dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                'Ok': function () {
                    var textValue = $(':txtValue').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Home/About',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { str: textValue },
                        success: function (result) {
                            alert(result.val);
                        }
                    });
                },
            }
        });
    });

</script>


     <input type="button" value="Add Value" class="button" />
     <div class="Text_dialog" title="Basic modal dialog">
          TextValue: <input type="text" class="txtValue" />
</div>
```

Control page:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult About(string str)
    {
        ValidateClass ObjAM = new ValidateClass();
        int value = ObjAM.ValidatetextValue(str);
        return Json(new { val = value });
    }
```

Model page:

```
 public class ValidateClass
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext dbObj = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        public int ValidatetextValue(string str)
        {
            string value = (from SearchtextValue in dbObj.Options
                                where SearchtextValue.OptionName == str
                                select SearchtextValue.OptionName).Single();
            if (value == null)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;

        }
    }
```

When i run this code i am getting script error like "Object doesn't support this property or method".Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change <strike>`data: { str: textValue }`</strike> to `data: "{ 'str' :'" + textValue +"' }"`

If you are confused on escaping the quotes properly, try this.

```
$(function() {
    $('.button').live('click', function() {
        $('.Text_dialog').dialog('open');
    });

    $('.Text_dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            'Ok': function() {
                var DTO = "{ 'str' :'" + $('.txtValue').val() +"' }";
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/About',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: DTO,
                    success: function(result) {
                        alert(result.val);
                    }
                });
            },
        }
    });
});
```

Please note that I have changed the <strike>`:txtValue`</strike> to `.txtValue` as it is the correct selector.

Comment: I am getting issue when page loading it self like 'type' is undefined.. Please help

Comment: be careful with the quotes. and make sure there are commas intact

Comment: Code is working fine.. but null value is exists to my control page instead of string which i enter in the textbox..

Comment: @Dhana: are you using `.txtValue` instead of *colon*

Comment: yes.. Please find my code here    var txtValue = "{ 'str' :'" + $('#txt1').val() + "' }";
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Home/About',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: txtValue,
                        success: function (result) {
                            alert(result.val);
                        }
                    });

Answer (score 0):

can you try changing

```
<input type="text" class="txtValue" />
```

to

```
<input type="text" class="txtValue" id="txtValue" />
```

and

```
var textValue = $(':txtValue').val();
```

to

```
var textValue = $('#txtValue').val();
```

I've never used `:` selector... but I think it will return you a collection and you should use index `[0]` or, why don't you use class selector `.`?

Edit: as I [see](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) you cannot use `:` in this case

also you can add `dataType: "json"`,into your Ajax request, and change your method return type from

```
public ActionResult About(string str)
```

to

```
public JsonResult About(string str)
```

EDIT 2:

have you included the library where  dialog() function is? after including the jquery library?

Comment: Yes i have added the Lib file after the JQ lib

Comment: Code is working fine.. but null value is exists to my control page instead of string which i enter in the textbox..Please advice

Comment: you should leave it as it was...
`data: { str: textValue }` ,this is the right way, in this waz you are sending an object that will be deserialized with request and serialized with the same name, at the server side...